# Sed failing to replace string in quotes during Gitlab CI

Tags: bash, sed, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

I am trying to dynamically set the image name and tag for AWS Elastic Beanstalk in my Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
"Image": {
  "Name": "IMAGETAG",
  "Update": "true"
}
```

with the following sed command as a script in my GitLab CI file:

```
sed -i.bak "s|IMAGETAG|$CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE|" Dockerrun.aws.json && rm Dockerrun.aws.json.bak; eb deploy Production
```

Where `$CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE` is a verified good environment variable (tested by doing `echo $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE` as a script). `$CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE` contains the structure of the following content (where ... is the full id):

```
gitlab.company.com:123/my-group/my-project:core_7de09851...8f_testing
```

The problem I am facing is that sed does not work during the CI pipeline. I am failing to understand why considering if I set the environment variable locally and run the same command, it will successfully replace the value of `Name` to the same structure URL. This testing was done on a Macbook.

I know that it is not updating the file because the Gitlab CI log reports

```
WARN: Failed to pull Docker image IMAGETAG:latest, retrying...
```

I've tried a few things that did not work:

- Running the `sed` and `eb deploy` commands as separate scripts (two different lines in the CI file)
- Switch the variable that I am seeking to replace in Dockerrun.aws.json to `<IMAGE>`
- While it was at `<IMAGE>`, running `sed -i='' "s|<IMAGE>|$CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE|" Dockerrun.aws.json` instead of doing the .bak and then rm'ing it (I read somewhere that sed has inconsistencies on OSX with the -i='' version)

Does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue might be and how it can be resolved?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. I am trying to replace a line in a java file in gitlab ci. The same works absolutely fine locally. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @DineshKumar I have just posted the solution, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two aspects of this that were going wrong:

1. The `sed` command was not executing correctly on the runner, but was working locally
2. `eb deploy` was ignoring the updated file

For part 1, he working `sed` command is:

`sed -ri "s|\"IMAGETAG\"|\"$1\"|" Dockerrun.aws.json`

where the line in Dockerrun.aws.json is `"Name": "IMAGETAG",`. `sed` still confuses me here so I can't explain why this one works vs the original command.

For part 2, apparently `eb deploy` will always look at the latest commit if it can, rather than the current working directory. Makes sense, I guess. To get around this, run the command as `eb deploy --staged`. You can read more about this flag on [AWS's site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html).

Also, note that my .gitlab-ci.yml simply calls a script to run all of this rather than doing it there.

```
- chmod +x ./scripts/ebdeploy.sh
- ./scripts/ebdeploy.sh $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
```